# How to prove uniform continuity using Weirstrasse M-Test?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I know: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2}}{n^3 + x^2}$ converges uniformly already, by:
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2}}{n^3 + x^2} \leq \sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}$ which I know converges by p-test with $p=3\gt1$.

But how do I prove that it has uniform convergence by the Weirstrasse M-Test?

Comment: What you are doing is an application of the Weierstrass M-Test. To be more precise: The M-test says that if $|f_n(x)| \leq a_n$ for all $x$ and $\sum_n a_n < \infty$, then $\sum_n f_n(x)$ converges uniformly. You apply that with $a_n = 1/n^3$.

Comment: @PhoemueX Is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2}}{n^3 + x^2}$ here $|f_n(x)|$, and my chosen $a_n = \frac{1}{n^3}$?